# Trying to use colliderect in pygame?

Tags: python

I'm trying to check for collisions, but whenever I try and run my code I receive an
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'colliderect')`.

Happens in this section of the code, the line underneath the second for loop.

```
# Collision

for i1 in range(len(enemies)):
    for i2 in range(1, len(enemies)):  # compares list against first index of last loop
        collision = enemies[i1].rect.x.colliderect(enemies[i2].rect.x)
        if i2 != i1:
            if collision:
                if enemies[i2].rect.x > enemies[i1].rect.x:
                    enemies[i2].rect.x += 6
                if enemies[i2].rect.x < enemies[i1].rect.x:
                    enemies[i2].rect.x -= 6
```

Comment: Just so you know: you can add pygame as a tag which will get you help quicker.

Comment: Because `enemies[i1].rect.x` is an integer value, not a `rect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't test the rect.x, you test the rect!

```
enemies[i1].rect.x.colliderect(enemies[i2].rect.x)
```

should be

```
enemies[i1].rect.colliderect(enemies[i2].rect)
```

You could also write:

```
for enemy1 in enemies:
    for enemy2 in enemies
        if enemy1 != enemy2:
            if enemy1.rect.colliderect(enemy2.rect)
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, pls click the tick to the left of the answer to mark it resolved.